# "From" multiple tables and then "LEFT JOIN" an other table

Tags: mysql

I have this query that works beautifully:

```
SELECT node.id, CONCAT( REPEAT( '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', (COUNT(parent.name_en) - 1) ), node.name_en) AS name_en_spaced, node.name_en as name_en, node.name_ar as name_ar, node.rgt as rgt,node.lft as lft, node.filter as filter
    FROM category AS node,
        category AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.id
    ORDER BY node.lft
```

When I add `LEFT JOIN` (I am just doing this to know if there are any records in `product` table related to a specific `category` regardless what they are or how many):

```
SELECT p.price,node.id, CONCAT( REPEAT( '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', (COUNT(parent.name_en) - 1) ), node.name_en) AS name_en_spaced, node.name_en as name_en, node.name_ar as name_ar, node.rgt as rgt,node.lft as lft, node.filter as filter
    FROM category AS node,
        category AS parent
    LEFT JOIN product AS p on node.id = p.category_id
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.id
    ORDER BY node.lft
```

I get this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'node.id' in 'on clause'` which is confusing. Can help me please!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing 2 ways of writing a join. In my opinion, it's better to always specify your join as it's easier to read after :

```
SELECT p.price,node.id,
 CONCAT( REPEAT( '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', (COUNT(parent.name_en) - 1) ), node.name_en) AS name_en_spaced,
 node.name_en as name_en,
 node.name_ar as name_ar,
 node.rgt as rgt,
 node.lft as lft, 
 node.filter as filter
FROM category AS node,
LEFT JOIN category AS parent
   ON node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.XXX = parent.XXX
LEFT JOIN product AS p on node.id = p.category_id
GROUP BY node.id
ORDER BY node.lft
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two type of join (cross & left). Try this:

```
SELECT p.price,node.id, CONCAT( REPEAT( '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', (COUNT(parent.name_en) - 1) ), node.name_en) AS name_en_spaced, node.name_en as name_en, node.name_ar as name_ar, node.rgt as rgt,node.lft as lft, node.filter as filter
    FROM category AS node
    LEFT JOIN category AS parent ON node.id = parent.id
    LEFT JOIN product AS p on node.id = p.category_id
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    GROUP BY node.id
    ORDER BY node.lft
```